# Paper JS unable to put a hole through Rectangle

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am unable to put a hole in a rectangle Path in Paper JS. I am using the subtract method. Anything I am doing wrong?

```js
var rect0 = new Path.Rectangle({
  point: [0, 0],
  size: [view.size.width],
  fillColor: "green",
  position: view.center
});



var rect = new Path.Rectangle({
  point: [0, 0],
  size: [view.size.width],
  fillColor: "#E50069",
  strokeWidth: 1
});

var rect2 = new Path.Rectangle({
  point: [0, 0],
  size: [50],
  fillColor: "white",
  position: view.center,
  strokeWidth: 1
});



rect3 = rect.unite(rect);

var drilled = rect3.subtract(rect2);

rect2.remove();
rect.remove();
```

[Here is a sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.3/S/tZLBTsMwDIZfxQqXIVVp2TQkgjggxH2CA4d1h6z1mmhpUiXeipj27iQtDITQDkjIh9iO/ftL5AOzskUm2PMWqVIsY5WrU5zncF/LjrCGjXctkELYOGNcr20DC+8qDCG5+CrbzqAobWxRRJ3I8+50zZ1vcoPS2xjk5DpdhXzUmXFFrSntaHvpwWNFBdyBxR4WkhR/iglpG4OTQ2kBOqctCVgWGRSrLGWCfsOY2GvsefJ5r2tS491GG/PgjPMCStZ4RFuybJQJmrSzAoa+Ci2hL+3x8vYnzP+wXDzOi+L65oMmkHdbfEm1Aq5OGJ8I078wzItfxvZKE577gnM4yRLOLOKkk+9sVJsk94u39nFeXJixZMbDbk1eVjSUTce6weUeW7fHSUoNat/i0sYlXHuU2+F5gYnl6vgO).

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is in the line `rect3 = rect.unite(rect);` which makes no sense.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.3/S/tZE9b8IwEIb/yskLqUijLF2MmFgYqzIwAINjDmLF8VWXC0hF/PfGTQliACYsWT6/7909/jipYGpUWi0qFFuqVFnaxr2l0AgUxlZ7pjZsYQoBj/BppMy+0IoJe4/Jac3rAN34JhdEwypPId+kF7VxP6jh4PCYxXDQd877GXliDaPCtziKxvltEpc4ezhfMC9jE3et7tBLegreMdX/CItBkOEdPvKBJHRrjjvz8UWXTsp5zx20rGkLYWMliSe6ll4TGGs6YNJbMelW6f60YDTV3zM1Sq82518=) demonstrating the solution with a more explicit code.

```
const background = new Path.Rectangle({
    point: [0, 0],
    size: view.size,
    fillColor: 'blue'
});

const rectangle = new Path.Rectangle({
    point: [0, 0],
    size: view.size,
    fillColor: 'orange'
});

const hole = new Path.Rectangle({
    from: view.center - 50,
    to: view.center + 50
});

const rectangleWithHole = rectangle.subtract(hole);

rectangle.remove();
hole.remove();
```